# return concatenation of 2 strings java

Tags: java, string

Basically, I'm looking to return the concatenation of 2 strings, However, if the concatenation creates a double-char, then I omit one of them.

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {
  if(a.isEmpty()){
     return b;
  }
  if(b.isEmpty()){
     return a;
  }
  if(a.substring(a.length()-1, a.length()).equals(b.substring(0,1))){
     return a+b.substring(1, b.length());
  }
  return a+b;
}
```

above is my code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with less code written, or to be more precise, if there a way to replace the first 2 conditions, with just a line or 2 of code.

Comment: I think Java has an inbuilt String.concat method.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_concat.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `charAt` instead of `subString` to obtain the 2 characters you want to compare :

```
if (a.charAt(a.length()-1)==b.charAt(0))
```

The first two conditions can be replaced by

```
if(a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty()) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Combining the two you can write :

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {
    if(a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty() || a.charAt(a.length()-1) != b.charAt(0)) {
        return a + b;
    } else {
        return a + b.substring(1, b.length());
    }
}
```

which can be replaced by a (quite long) one liner :

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {
    return (a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty() || a.charAt(a.length()-1) != b.charAt(0)) ? (a + b) : (a + b.substring(1, b.length()));
}
```

This is assuming neither of the input Strings can be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {
   return a + ((a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty()) || b.charAt(0) != a.charAt(a.length() - 1) ? b : b.substring(1, b.length()));
}
```

Explanation:

- always return `a+(next expression)`
- next expression `check if a or b is empty or they don't have common char at a's  last position and b's start position if any other condition becomes true means we have to add substring of b starts from the 1'st index.`
- if above condition fails then just add b to a and return;